# Crontab forever start in production mode

Tags: node.js, cron, forever

I'm running Ghost blog on a MEAN stack. I'm using forever to keep the blog alive after starting it. I've also setup crontab to launch the `forever start` command on server reboot.

I can't work out how to get it to start in production mode with crontab.
If I did this straight into the command line, I'd do this:

```
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
```

That works great, but the following line in my crontab ignores the production mode part and starts it in development mode:

```
@reboot NODE_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/forever start /path/to/blog/index.js
```

Comment: I don't think you should use crontab for starting a service like forever. Instead, I'd use an /etc/init.d script. See, for example, https://www.exratione.com/2013/02/nodejs-and-forever-as-a-service-simple-upstart-and-init-scripts-for-ubuntu/

Comment: @IvanKrechetov Thanks, I'll definitely look into that method. In the mean time, do you know if this is possible with crontab?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the environment variable for all lines, do it like this:

```
NODE_ENV=production 
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /path/to/blog/index.js
```

Unfortunately you need to make a `.sh` to set it per line.

Comment: If I have some `@reboot` lines before the `NODE_ENV=production`, will they  not be affected by the production declaration?